# How to count how many repeated numbers in a file and then organize them by repetitions?

Tags: bash, awk

I have to make a bash script that counts all numbers of 1 to 45 in a text file and displays the number of repetitions for each number, sorted from most repeated to least.

example: file.txt

```
7   22  22   7  13  31
13  13   7  13  13  40
```

output: output.txt

```
13 = 5
7 = 3
22 = 2
31 = 1
40 = 1
```

Comment: This question already has an answer in [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/521891/counting-occurrences-in-first-column-of-a-file) by piping the input to `sort -n | uniq -c` and awk variants.

Comment: @Mephy no, it doesn't since that question only had 1 value per line while this has multiple, and the solution you suggested similarly won't work for this question.

Comment: @EdMorton the question is about counting the repetitions, and not preparing the input to match it. That answer will work for this question, as we can see in Karoly's answer. Not that its a problem, cross-site question duplicates are completely fine if its on-topic for both sites, I just referenced a working solution.

Comment: @Mephy counting repetitions that are on separate lines is absolutely trivial, as seen in that other question, counting them when they can occur on the same line is a harder task not addressed by that other question. This is not a duplicate of that other question.

Answer (score 3):

```
tr -s " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n r | awk '{print $2 " = " $1}'
# each item in |     count      |    sort   |   fix output format
#  a new line
```

Comment: You'll need to add `sort -n -r` before the `awk` since the user wants the output sorted by frequency, but otherwise this is great.

Comment: Thx, haven't noticed that requirement.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]` and sorted `in`:

```
$ awk -v RS='\\s+' '{cnt[$0]++} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"; for (i in cnt) print i" = "cnt[i]}' file
13 = 5
7 = 3
22 = 2
31 = 1
40 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ tr -s ' ' '\n' <file | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | awk '{print $2 " = " $1}'
13 = 5
7 = 3
22 = 2
40 = 1
31 = 1
```

also if additional sorting on the numerical values needed change to

```
$ tr -s ' ' '\n' <nums | sort | uniq -c | sort -k1,1nr -k2n | awk '{print $2 " = " $1}'
13 = 5
7 = 3
22 = 2
31 = 1
40 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

this awk one-liner should give your the report in one shot:

```
awk -v RS=" +|\n" '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a)printf "%d = %d\n",x,a[x]}' file
```

If you want to sort the output by frequency descending, just pipe the output to `sort -nr -k3`

test with your data:

```
kent$  awk -v RS=" +|\n" '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a)printf "%d = %d\n",x,a[x]}' f|sort -nr -k3
13 = 5
7 = 3
22 = 2
31 = 1
40 = 1
```